# Concatenate list of columns except when any of them is null

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe for which I want to add a new column, which is a concatenation of all the items from the columns in listOfFixedColumns using "_". I want to set the new column's value to null if any of the columns in listOfFixedColumns is null.

```
+---+----+---------+
|  a|   b| unique_id |
+---+----+---------+
|foo | bar|  foo_bar|
|null|bar |    null |
|baz |null|    null |
|null|null|    null |
+---+----+---------+
```

I tried this which gets me only the concatenated column values

```
val listOfFixedColumns = List("A", "B", ..) // dynamic list of columns names as strings
df.withColumn("unique_id", concat_ws("_", listOfFixedColumns.map(c => col(c)): _*))
```

but I am not able to figure out how to take care of the null cases:

```
+---+----+---------+
|  a|   b|unique_id|
+---+----+---------+
|foo | bar|  foo_bar|
|null|bar |    bar  |<-- needs a fix
|baz |null|    baz  |<-- needs a fix
|null|null|    null |
+---+----+---------+
```

Do I have to use UDFs for this? I am a Scala beginner and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isNull`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cc06266ade5a4eb35089501a3b32736624208d4c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L590) method of Column class, together with the `OR` operator to find out when there is a null column. Then use is it in a condition with [`when`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cc06266ade5a4eb35089501a3b32736624208d4c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L1373):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat_ws, when}

val df = Seq(
  ("foo", "bar", "foo_bar"),
  (null, "bar", null),
  ("baz", null, null),
  (null, null, null)
).toDF("A", "B", "C")

val listOfFixedColumns = List("A", "B", "C")
val hasNull = listOfFixedColumns
                      .map(col(_).isNull)
                      .reduce(_ || _)

val concatNonEmpty = concat_ws("_", listOfFixedColumns.map(col): _*)

df.withColumn("unique_id", when(!hasNull, concatNonEmpty).otherwise(null)).show

// +----+----+-------+---------------+
// |   A|   B|      C|      unique_id|
// +----+----+-------+---------------+
// | foo| bar|foo_bar|foo_bar_foo_bar|
// |null| bar|   null|           null|
// | baz|null|   null|           null|
// |null|null|   null|           null|
// +----+----+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: Of course in your real life situation, you might use df.columns (possibly removing columns you dont want to include) to write more robust code.

Comment: I think @kumar's case requires to apply the logic on a subset of the columns not all of them.

Comment: . It wasn't a criticism, just a remark for future readers who may have a very similar but not exact scenario. Great answer!